# Can't grab _GET params due to NGINX rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I'm having trouble with my nginx .htaccess rewrite rules and I could really use some help as it's breaking my whole website.

So I'm rewriting my  `?page=` _GET parameter to something similar to this: `website.com/page/` and that actually works, but when I try to grab my _GET['page']  parameter it returns an array with key 0 without a value.

My .htaccess looks like this:

## nginx configuration

```
charset utf-8;

    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 break;
        }
    }
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: First, nginx has no `.htaccess`. Second, show full nginx config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$path = $parsed['path'];
$path_parts = explode('/', $path);
$desired_part = $path_parts[1];
```

This takes your URI segments and explodes them and puts them into an array. Then  if your example.com/index.php?page=1 url becomes example.com/page/1 you can pull the one out of the $path_parts array ie:

```
 $desired_output = $path_parts[3]; // Would return 1 in the 'example.com/page/1' example above.
```

When your url is formatted like that you can't grab the $_GET parameters because they don't exist anymore.

I suggest var_dumping some of the above variables and play with it a little bit.

Comment: It works! I was actually able to still get my _GET parameters with apache2 rewriterules, so I was really confused when it didn't work for nginx. Thanks for showing me this approach! :)